# What is a good way to write/read large binary data to/from file?

Tags: c#, binary

I have larger amount of binary data to store to .bin file. I store binary value to string data type and than write it to .bin file multiple times, because data is too long to store it in one string variable and then write it to file. The problem is when I try to read this data from file I need to read it partialy and store it to string variable, than use and empty that string and repeat the process. I have hard time doing just that, because i don't read data correctly ( it reads it correctly first time, but when it reads data to string again it messes something up - I think it starts reading from begining of file again instead of where it left off). If anybody has any idea on how to read and store larger amount of binary data in one step or do my implementation better it would be in great help. Thank you in advance :)

This is my code so far:

```
static string ReadBinary()
{
    string temp = "";

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:/Compression/compressed.bin", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    if (fs.CanRead)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length/8];
        int bytesread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesread);
    }
    
    /*BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    string temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(br.ReadBytes(1000));
    br.Close();*/
    fs.Close();
    
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Exactly 1.54 MB, but it doesn't get stored on string variable. I need suitable data type for binary reading.

Comment: _The problem is when I try to read this data from file I need to read it partialy and store it to string variable_ Why don't read/write to binary? What the data looks like? Can't you serialize as json or xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it starts reading from begining of file again instead of where it left off

That's actually correct, given that the code says

```
int bytesread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

and the documentation for the second parameter is:

> The byte offset in array at which the read bytes will be placed.

So, every time you start reading from the beginning instead of where you left off on the previous read.

Rather than fixing that, I'd suggest you to simplify your code *significantly*, since 1.54MB is a small file. I'd also suggest you to use an appropriate data structure for the data, a `string` is for storing characters, not binary data, so a `byte[]` makes more sense here.

Overall, you can reduce your entire code to just:

```
private static byte[] ReadBinary()
{
    return File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:/Compression/compressed.bin");
}
```

Comment: why is byte array after reading with your approach filled with numbers like 49 and 48 ...? how do I get binary value out of this?

Comment: @TomažKlobučar Those *are* binary values :). Unless you stored the binary data as string, in that case, you would need to do `Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes(ReadBinary())`

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with the file in MBs

you can use

```
static string ReadBinary()
{
    return File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Compression/compressed.bin");
}
```

Or if you want `byte[]` which is correct dataType for storing binary information you can do

```
static byte[] ReadBinary()
{
    return File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:/Compression/compressed.bin");
}
```

Comment: ReadAllBytes returns byte[] not string.

Answer (score -2):

The routine below will use 2 streams to read and write the binary data. I don't think setting the Position is needed but just to be sure it is at the start of the stream. You can also add a seconde parameter to the the CopyTo(source, buffersize) routine. The buffersize has a default but you can set smaller or larger values.

```
    private void Copy(string source, string dest)
    {
        using (var inputFileStream = File.OpenRead(source))
        using (var outputFileStream = File.Open(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            inputFileStream.Position = 0; // Just to be sure it is at the start of the stream

            inputFileStream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
        }
    }
```